# onClick event and 'Spacebar' keypress event on a button

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, onclick, ms-access-2010

I have a form made in MS Access which contains a button. 
I am displaying a message box on onClick event of the button. However, user can navigate to that button using Tab key also and then press spacebar, and expects the same behaviour to take place as that of onClick event.

Is there a way to effectively implement this? Or the only way is to call the same subroutine from two places - one which handles onClick event and second which handles 'Spacebar' key press event.

Comment: Tabbing to a command button (so that it has focus) then pressing Enter or space has the same effect as clicking the command button with the mouse ... the button's On Click event fires.  Is your Access application behaving differently or did I just misunderstand your question?

Comment: As @HansUp said, the behaviour that you described should work without further code. If you're not getting the OnClick event fired when the focus is on it and you are pressing the spacebar, then it's either not a proper button control or something else is amiss.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't attach the result of the message box to another onClick, instead you should get the result in your existing sub and work from there.  For example:

```
Answer = MsgBox("Do you want to continue ?", vbYesNo)
If Answer = vbYes Then
  Code for YES
Else
  Code for NO
EndIf
```

Knowing a bit more about what your messagebox and code do would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to your problem:

1. Disable the `Button_OnKey` events and only allow `OnClick` event
2. Allow the OnKey events but call the same sub that handles the `OnClick`
3. Remove the `OnClick` event code, since the user will be able to either press the button from the keyboard, or by the click of a mouse, in both cases, `Button_Click` event is triggered, so it is safer to put the handling code in the `Button_Click` event